# JBoss eap 6 (as 7) - 2 different classes with same package and name

Tags: jboss, classloader

I am having an issue with a 3rd party developer.
They have provided a number of jars, and unfortunately in 2 different jars they have different implementations of a class (same name, same package).

We deploy using a single war file where both jars (among many others) are packaged together in web-inf/lib directory and unfortunately both jars are needed.

Is there a way where I can guarantee in JBoss eap 6 that the class from a.jar gets loaded before the class from b.jar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All of your answers about classloading on JBoss can be found [here at this link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7). But since now I advise you to read the "JBoss Deployment Structure File" section

With the "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" JBoss specific deployment descriptor you can control class loading in a fine grained manner. It should be placed in the top level deployment, in META-INF (or WEB-INF for web deployments). It can do the following:

`Prevent automatic dependencies from being added`

`Add additional dependencies`

`Define additional modules`

`Change an EAR deployments isolated class loading behaviour`

`Add additional resource roots to a module`